# C# ClientSize wrong calculated

Tags: c#

I run a Application where the ClientSize of my Controls get calculated wrong.

When I do the following steps in debug mode I found out:
[image]

In the normal mode I get the wrong value:

```
var x = linePanel.ClientSize.Width;
>>> x = 40
```

`linePanel` is a normal panel from `System.Windows.Forms` with a `BorderStyle.Fixed3D`. So that's why the `ClientSize.Width` should be **36**. I have no idea why my application have this behavior and the workaround is horrible, because I have to program the correct value hard inside the code.

Thankful for any response.

**EDIT: Minimal Example for Console-App (.Net Framework 4.6.1):**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tools
{
    //BASE IS A CONSOLE-APP (.NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.1)
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //MAIN
            Run(new Action(() => UI()));
        }

        public static void Run(Action xAction)
        {
            //RUN AS STA (SINGLETHREAD-APARTMENT)
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false); xAction(); are.Set(); are.WaitOne(); }));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        public static void UI()
        {
            //UI
            Form f = new Form();
            f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Size s = f.ClientSize;
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong ClientSize: " + s); //WRONG CLIENT SIZE IS 284, 261
            Console.WriteLine("Correct ClientSize: (280, 257)"); //CORRECT CLIENT SIZE AFTER OPEN DETAILS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `In the normal mode` What is **normal mode**?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman hello Progman, thanks for your advice. I added a minimal example running exactly as described on my system. Hope it is verifiable.

Comment: Your code is an mcve now, but your reasoning is hard to folow. Your 'modes' are still not clear.  A new Form may fire some resize events when it organizes itself.

Comment: @mjwills and @Henk Holterman sorry for the confusion. Talking from `normal mode` was not clever. With `debug mode` I mean the **VS Debug Mode with set breakpoints** (to investigate the details of the object) and with `Normal mode` I mean **VS Debug Mode without breakpoints**.